# use KissXML and armv7 GoogleMap

Tags: ios, google-maps, kissxml

i need some help,
I met this problem, i need use googleMap in my project,and I must do the following operation:
Replace the default value of Architectures with `armv7`.

In the Other Linker Flags section, add `-ObjC`. 
If these settings are not visible, change the filter in the Build Settings bar from Basic to All.
But if i do this, the KissXML don't work...

Some Error like this:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DDXMLInvalidNode in:
/Users/zxguo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AvePoint.CRM.TimeLine.IPhone-drfocqfderkbqcgsikoffypeyhek/Build/Intermediates/CRMTimeLine.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CRMTimeLine.build/Objects-normal/i386/DDXMLNode.o
/Users/zxguo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AvePoint.CRM.TimeLine.IPhone-drfocqfderkbqcgsikoffypeyhek/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CRMTimeLineCore.framework/CRMTimeLineCore(DDXMLNode.o)
ld: 16 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't know how to do. Please help me.Thanks very much.

Comment: Did you add some DDXMLNode.m into your project? Linker just said to you that it won't compile because it has found the same references of the same thing in two different binary (DDXMLNode.o from CRMTimeLineCore.framework and another DDXMLNode.o into ../i386/), and it doesn't know which one to choose. If no, do a clean of your build and project (to clean the derived data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Project files, it appears that you have DDXMLNode more than once in your project. Check other duplicated files as well. After that it should build.